# Cant get image size once the browser starts the first time

Tags: javascript, image, image-size

I have currently a problem with getting the width of an image once I start the Browser the first time. I get every time the value 0 instead the right width. If I start the Browser and refresh the page with f5, I get the correct value.

How could I handle that Problem? Here my code part:

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    ...
        function () {            
            img = new Image();
            img.src = 'images/flags/medium/' + flag + '.png';
            img.onload = $(function() {
                if(img.width > size[0]) {
                    size[0] = img.width;
                }
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    $('#list1').append(
                    $('<li id=item' + j + '>'));
                    $('#item' + j).append(img);
                    $('#item' + j).append(
                            $('<li>').append(company).addClass('company')
                    );
                    i = 1;
                } else {
                    $('#list2').append(
                    $('<li id=item' + j + '>'));
                    $('#item' + j).append(img);
                    $('#item' + j).append(
                            $('<li>').append(company).addClass('company')
                    );
                    i = 0;
                }
                j++;
            });

        }
```

`size[0]` is at the first start of the Browser `0`, after refresh it has the correct value. Why? Greetz.

**Edit**
Well, it seems, that the problem sometimes also occur once I hammer f5.

Comment: Chrome, FF newest version and IE 9, 8, 7. Greetz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:  `img.onload = $(function() {`

to: `img.onload=(function() {`

seems to work fine with random images from google on the first load.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuCLf/25/)

Comment: actually just get rid of the '$' in this line: `img.onload = $(function() {`

Comment: Do you mean to insert the `img.onload` code into `$(document).imagesLoaded`? Sorry, I dont get it.

Comment: Yea the `$` was the problem, why?

Comment: probably something to do with mixing jquery and javascript syntax. jquery is best when used with dom elements, js is for more behind the scenes manipulation i suppose.